# Using parser_combinators to parse a string

Tags: parsing, rust

I am playing with Rust, and am trying to write a simple parser.

I need to parse the string:

```
"0123,456789"
```

into a stucture:

```
Passport { label : i8 = 0, body : i32 = 123456789 }
```

I am using `parser_combinators` and my code is working, but very ugly.

How can I rewrite this code?

```
extern crate parser_combinators as pc;
 use pc::*;
 use pc::primitives::{State, Stream};

 fn main() {
     match parser(parse_passport).parse("a123,456") {
         Ok((r,l)) => println!("{} {} {}", r.label, r.body, l),
         Err(e) => println!("{}", e)
     }
 }

 struct Passport {
     label : i8,
     body  : i32,
 }

 fn parse_passport<I>(input: State<I>) -> ParseResult<Passport, I> where I: Stream<Item=char> {
     let mut label = digit().map(|i : char| (i as i8) - ('0' as i8));
     let mut fst = many1(digit()).map(|string : String| string.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
     let (i,input) = match label.parse_state(input) {
         Ok((x,n)) => (x,n.into_inner()),
         Err(e) => return Err(e)
     };
     let (f,input) = match fst.parse_state(input) {
         Ok((x,n)) => (x,n.into_inner()),
         Err(e) => return Err(e)
     };
     let (_,input) = match satisfy(|c| c == ',').parse_state(input) {
         Ok((x,n)) => (x,n.into_inner()),
         Err(e) => return Err(e)
     };
     let (s,input) = match fst.parse_state(input) {
         Ok((x,n)) => (x,n),
         Err(e) => return Err(e)
     };
     let p = Passport { label : i, body : f * 1000000 + s };
     Ok((p, input))
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We're glad you decided to move your code here from Stack Overflow. I hope you get some great answers!

Comment: Could you double check your example code? You are parsing `a123,456`, not `0123,456`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small style nits to fix before we dive into the meat. When specifying a variable and a type, there should be space after the `:`, but not before:

```
// label : i8,
label: i8,
```

I break `where` clauses onto the next line, with each type restriction on its own line as well:

```
// fn parse_passport<I>(input: State<I>) -> ParseResult<Passport, I> where I: Stream<Item=char> {
fn parse_passport<I>(input: State<I>) -> ParseResult<Passport, I>
    where I: Stream<Item=char>
{
```

Let the compiler use type inference as much as possible. You don't always need to specify the type of a closure variable, for instance:

```
// let mut label = digit().map(|i : char| (i as i8) - ('0' as i8));
let mut label = digit().map(|i| (i as i8) - ('0' as i8));
```

Using [`try!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html) is going to be your biggest win for clarity:

```
// let (i,input) = match label.parse_state(input) {
//     Ok((x,n)) => (x,n.into_inner()),
//     Err(e) => return Err(e)
// };
let (i, input) = try!(label.parse_state(input));
let input = input.into_inner();
```

That's as far as I got with generic Rust knowledge. After reading the docs a bit, I came up with this though (**note**: this is my first time using this library, so I make no claims to use it well!):

```
fn parse_passport<I>(input: State<I>) -> ParseResult<Passport, I>
    where I: Stream<Item=char>
{
    let label = digit().map(|i| (i as i8) - ('0' as i8));
    fn to_number(string: String) -> i32 { string.parse().unwrap() }
    let fst = many1(digit());
    let comma = satisfy(|c| c == ',');

    let mut parser = label.and(fst.clone().map(to_number)).and(comma).and(fst.map(to_number));

    let ((((i, f), _), s), input) = try!(parser.parse_state(input));

    let p = Passport { label: i, body: f * 1000000 + s };

    Ok((p, input))
}
```

I'm certain there's a better way though. The nested tuples are a bit off-putting. Also, I feel like there should be a nice way to `map` over the result of the parsing so we didn't have to unpack and repack the Result, including the `input`. There's the straight forward but awkward:

```
parser.parse_state(input).map(|((((i, f), _), s), input)| {
    (Passport { label: i, body: f * 1000000 + s }, input)
})
```

This is the final thing I ended up at:

```
extern crate parser_combinators as pc;
use pc::*;
use pc::primitives::{State, Stream};

fn main() {
    match parser(parse_passport).parse("0123,456789") {
        Ok((r, l)) => println!("{} {} {}", r.label, r.body, l),
        Err(e)     => println!("{}", e)
    }
}

struct Passport {
    label: i8,
    body: i32,
}

fn parse_passport<I>(input: State<I>) -> ParseResult<Passport, I>
    where I: Stream<Item=char>
{
    let label = digit().map(|i| (i as i8) - ('0' as i8));
    fn to_number(string: String) -> i32 { string.parse().unwrap() }
    let fst = many1(digit());
    let comma = satisfy(|c| c == ',');

    let mut parser = label.and(fst.clone().map(to_number)).and(comma).and(fst.map(to_number));

    parser.parse_state(input).map(|((((i, f), _), s), input)| {
        (Passport { label: i, body: f * 1000000 + s }, input)
    })
}
```